# I'd like to remove arrow of submenu of TPopupMenu in delphi

Tags: delphi, gdi

I want to remove the arrow that appears in the submenu of TMenuItem in delphi.

I tried to this code. And then the arrow was removed but can not be repaint TMenuItem after the first item that 'Robot Information'.

[image] [image]

```
procedure TForm1.DrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  iHeight: Integer;
  dc: HDC;
begin
  try
    ACanvas.TextOut(ARect.Left, ARect.Top, (Sender as TMenuItem).Caption);
    dc := ACanvas.Handle;
    ExcludeClipRect(dc, ARect.Left, ARect.Top, ARect.Right, ARect.Bottom);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, dc);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The arrow appears when the menu item has child items. Why do you want to hide the arrow, and not indicate to the user that there are child items? Also, please clarify what the problem with the top item, `Robot information` is, it's unclear.

Comment: Hardly surprising that this code fails given the call to `ReleaseDC`. What are you hoping to achieve with that call to `ReleaseDC`?

Comment: The DC belongs to the TCanvas. It's not yours to release. It's unclear what you're asking. Menu items that have children show the arrow to tell the user the children are there. If you don't want child items on the menu, don't add child items in the first place.

Comment: Anyway, custom drawing, like you do, should do the trick, if implemented correctly. See also  [How to custom draw menu items](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27128) for an example.

Comment: Above all, Thank's comments. In fact i'd like to change the image of arrow. So i have inserted image on 'DrawEvent' but original image appear in front. I know the reason because the event that shown original image of arrow happen after 'DrawEvent'. What should i do for this?